# Excel table object: How to increment numbers when value changes in another column?

Tags: excel, countif

I have a range of cells in Table format in excel. How to increment numbers in a table column when value changes in each group with a formula?

I tried using the formula B2=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2) which creates a number sequence that restarts for every change in another column. This works well for tables with fixed number of rows. The problem arrives when adding new rows to the table since the range shifts to adjust to the table range. Example for row 2:
FROM COUNTIF($B$2:B2;B2) to COUNTIF($B$2:B3;B2) instead of keeping COUNTIF($B$2:B2;B2) unchanged.

How to avoid such behaviour when adding new rows?

Desired result:

[image: Product Number A 1 A 2 A 3 B 1 B 2 A 4 A 5 C 1 C 2 A 6 (...)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a table, I'd suggest structured references like:

```
=COUNTIF(Table1[[#Headers],[Product]]:[@Product],[@Product])
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the same results as you do -- when I insert a row, the criteria cell changes.

In any event, since this is a Table, you can use structured references:

```
B2: =COUNTIF(INDEX([Product],1):@[Product],@[Product])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This option doesn't seem to create an incremental value sequence for each cell within that group. For each repeated cell value in Product, it shows the total number of items found in the range e.g. 4,4,4,4, instead of 1,2,3,4.

Comment: @David I will add a screen shot demonstrating that this method works. You just enter the formula in B2 (with the rest of Column B blank) and the formula will automatically populate the rest of the column.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. When I replicated I got:                             Product Number
A             7
A             7
A             7
B             2
B             2
A             7
A             7
C             2
C                  2
A             7
A             7

Comment: @David  copy/paste the exact formula you entered into B2 here in a comment

Comment: =COUNTIF(INDEX([Product];1):[Product];[Product])

Comment: I understood the issue. I had already 12 rows pre-populated in column A. When I drag and drop the formula in B it doesn't seem to work with automatic calculation mode. But it does work if I add row by row in the table under calculation mode manual

Comment: @David  What you copy/pasted is **not** the same formula  I suggested. In particular, you are missing the very necessary `@`'s.  And you should be clearing out the contents of  column b and only entering the formula in B2.

Comment: Thanks. In fact the formula that works in my computer is COUNTIF(INDEX([Product];1):[@Product];[@Product]). The @ needs to be inside []. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @David Interesting. On mine it works either way.  Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

David, if your cells are not formatted as an Excel Table, this formula can do the job:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A1:A" & COUNTA(A:A)),A1)-COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A"&ROW() & ":A" & COUNTA(A:A)),A1)+1
```

Comment: Thanks. This option doesn't seem to create an incremental value sequence for each cell within that group. For each repeated cell value in Product, it shows the total number of items found in the range e.g. 4,4,4,4, instead of 1,2,3,4.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't paid enough attention at first. But now the formula produces the desired sequence. Please take a look.